# Difference between Project Location and Project Folder in Netbeans?

Tags: ide, netbeans

I'm creating a new project in Netbeans 6.9, and it's asking me for a `Project Location` and a `Project Folder`. What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project location path specifies the directory where your project folder will be located.

For example, assume you have some directory d. You want to build a new project and you want to store the project in a folder named x. You decide that x should be located in directory d. Then your project location will be d and your project folder will be x. The paths that would be supplied to Netbeans for project location and project folder are the paths of d and x, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Netbeans help page does a good job explaining it.

- **Project Name**. Specifies the display name of the project. This name is also used to create the project folder and the context path.
- **Project Location**. Specifies the location where you want to store the project metadata and source code.
- **Project Folder**. Specifies the folder where you want to store the project metadata and source code. The folder is a concatenation of the **project location** and the **project name**.